# EC2 Windows Server 2016 has a "vEthernet (nat)" adapter

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016

I have several windows 2016 servers in my EC2 environments.

On only one of them, I keep getting this "nat" virtual adapter which is assigned a 172.16 IP address.

I think it is mucking up DNS conditional forwarding and some other things.

Why is it there?

How do I get rid of it?

I've already tried "delete" in the Network control panel -- this fails.

"Disable" in the same control panel just creates a new one on reboot, with a trailing number. e.g. "vEthernet (nat) 2"

I can provide whatever other details as necessary -- unfortunately my expertise is Linux, not Windows, so offhand, I'm not sure what else to provide.

Answer (score 1):

I am not positive this is the actual answer, but here's the solution that worked for me:

It turned out I had installed Windows **2019** server, not **2016**.

I'm not sure if this is a "feature" or "bug" or "normal behavior" but on the 2019 server, **on EC2**, a virtual ethernet NAT adapter appears on every reboot. This adapter gets a 172.16 IP address.

This appeared to cause a problem where the DNS entry for the server had both the 172. IP address and the 10. IP address. I only wanted the 10. I'm pretty sure this was causing lookup problems across domains such that the corresponding trust domain could not find a controller for the 2019 server's domain.

My solution was to nuke the 2019 server and install from a Windows 2016 Server AMI.

This new server configured as I expected, and I did not hit any hiccups.

I'd love to see if anyone knows any more about this behavior on Windows 2019, and if my speculation is correct, and if it is a bug or feature. The Windows 2019-specific docs on Microsoft are terrible -- heck, the 2016 docs aren't even fully up to date yet.